# If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ both converge to $N(0,1)$ in distribution, and $\mathrm{Cov}(X_n, Y_n)=0$ for each $n$, what does $(X_n\ Y_n)^T$ converges to?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ both converge to $N(0,1)$ in distribution, and for each $n$, both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have zero mean and unit variance. Additionally, $\mathrm{Cov}(X_n, Y_n)=0$ for each $n$. Does the vector $\begin{bmatrix}X_n\\ Y_n \end{bmatrix}$ converges to $N(\begin{bmatrix}0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$, the answer is "yes." If they are merely uncorrelated, the answer is "not necessarily."

For a counterexample, take $X$ and $Y$ to be standard normal, with zero correlation but not independent. Define $(X_n,Y_n):=(X,Y)$ for each $n$. Then each $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge to $N(0,1)$ in distribution since they're already $N(0,1)$. But the limiting joint distribution is that of $(X,Y)$.

The classic example: Let $X$ have standard normal distribution. Toss a fair coin independently of $X$. If the coin lands heads, let $Y=X$; else let $Y=-X$. You can check that $Y$ has standard normal distribution. Also $E(XY)=0$, hence $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

No.

We cannot even conclude that as $n\to\infty$, we have convergence in distribution $(X_n, Y_n)\overset{d}{\to}(X, Y)$ where $(X,Y)$ is a random vector with marginal distributions $N(0,1)$. Even if you have convergence in distribution, you may hope that since $\text{Cov}(X_n,Y_n)=0$ then $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ and thus $(X,Y)\sim N(\boldsymbol{0}, I)$. There are two problems with this. Firstly, it may happen that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Cov}(X_n,Y_n)\ne \text{Cov}(X,Y)$$
For this to be true, you'd need convergence in expectations of various kinds, which is asking for a lot more than what you originally did. Secondly, even if the above limit were to hold, $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ is not enough for $(X,Y)\sim N(\boldsymbol{0},I)$. You need $(X,Y)$ to be jointly normal for this to be true, and the conditions you gave were not enough to guarantee this, either.

Comment: It's not even true that $(X_n, Y_n)$ necessarily converges in distribution to anything. If $X$, $Y$ are iid standard normals and $I$ is a random sign, then the sequence that alternates between $(X, Y)$ and $(X, IX)$ satisfies the marginal and covariance conditions but doesn't converge in distribution.

Comment: Fair point, I overlooked that. Thanks, I'll edit my answer.